# Live Share audio not showing up in Visual Studio 2019 Pro edition

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 Pro and am in a Live Share connection.  I'm trying to get the audio feature, but can't find it anywhere.  What am I missing

Comment: Do you mean this preview extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-audio ? (For VS-Code... maybe there is something similar is the VS extension gallery)

Comment: That extension is for VS Code.  I updated the extension in VS Pro, but the Audio still isn't there

Answer (score 2):

This feature is now available in Visual Studio, but it is currently in insiders channel.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/insiders

> By default, after installing the Visual Studio Live Share extension,
> you're using the Stable feature set, which includes all of the
> production-ready capabilities (e.g. co-editing, shared debugging,
> terminals). However, if you'd like to get early access to feature
> we're working on, you can opt-in to the Insiders feature set by
> changing the following setting in your IDE:
> [image]

After enabling the insiders channel, you will notice the "Start audio Call" option in Live Share window within Visual Studio.

**UPDATE:** Do remember to restart Visual Studio for these changes to take effect.

Comment: And restart Visual Studios, otherwise it won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Audio calls is not supported in Live Share for Visual Studio. Currently, it is an [open feature](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/741) request in the live-share github repository.